# Qt5/Qml app: corrupt text on Win7 / empty window on WinXp

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Problems in Qt5.4 Qml app on Windows (built with Qt Creator Mingw-32bit): on Win7 some text fields fonts are corrupt ( http://goo.gl/C0UD0j ), on WinXP only empty frame ( http://goo.gl/8iF67W ). On Linux app runs ok: http://goo.gl/0dscSW .

Comment: I had sometimes problem with corrupted fonts. After searching I've come to conclusion that was a problem with old OpenGL/driver. So after updating fonts display correctly.

Comment: Adding to @folibis improtant advice, you can also use `renderType: Text.NativeRendering` to rasterize the glyphs via the system back-end, instead of Qt.

Comment: @folibis tried to switch renderer, but that not helped: http://goo.gl/xsD81s . Text corrupted in all TextAreas, and sometimes in CheckBoxes. Compiled  Debug config, app starts and runs normally, without exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text corruption on Win7 solved by video driver upgrade. Empty window on XP caused by Opengl-only Mingw-build of Qt5/QtCreator. Switched to VS2013 Qt build with Angle support, and recompiled with right switches ( http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=423 ) , now app runs on XP.